# flot chart does not stack multiple series with null at some points in series

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, stacked

I am trying to plot stacked area ( filled line ) with stacking using flot charts
my data is is like

```
series 1: [0,5],[1,3],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2]

series 2: [0,5],[1,2],[2,null],[3,1],[4,2]

series 3: [0,5],[1,3],[2,2],[3,5],[4,2]
```

as in above case at point 2, flot is not plotting series 3 : [2,2]
I see chart plotting 3 series in stack, but at point 2 its only one value ( series 1 with value 2 )

here is jsfiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/judaq/7/

Comment: What tool you are using?

Comment: I am using flot charts.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using a 0 instead of null.

**Edit**

```
var series = [{
    data: [
        [0,5],[1,3],[2,2],[3,2],[4,9]
    ],
    label: "Series 1"
},
{
    data: [[0,5],[1,3],[2,2],[3,0],[4,9]
          ], 
    label: "Series 2"
}, {
    data: [
        [0,5],[1,3],[2,2],[3,5],[4,9]
    ],
    label: "Series 3"
}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KieranDotCo/judaq/

Comment: the graph is for response time, 0 would mean that response time is 0 , and it would connect series 2 points. As i need to represent hole ( null ) for that series at that point. I am stacking multiple urls response time, and as different url ( series 1, 3 ) has response time, That should be stacked over hole ( null )

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the stack plugin in flot.

See the [github issue #740](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/740).